# Content viewing app - tech advice

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

We have a requirement to provide a fairly rich interface as part of a community, which allows for browsing and viewing videos.

We must also provide some analytics for the product team. Which will be an external system and unlikely Google Analytics.

It's clear that we will need to host the videos elsewhere (cdn).

I want some guidence on if LWC or Aura or VF + angular (or something) is the best way to go?

What with the locker service restricting 3rd party libraries which I'm sure we will need (for analytics etc) and a rich interface, I'm tending towards a complete build in angular, then dropping it into VF for connectivity to the SF APIs.
This would also have to be responsive.

Is there anything I'm missing here? I can't use LWC or aura 40+ as I know I'll need a 3rd party library at point.